# PHP imagerotate is cropping image

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I am writing a script that takes an arrow image and rotates it by a set number of degrees. Using the code below, when the angle is a multiple of 90 the image rotates and displays as expected.

The source image looks like this (74 x 74):

[image]

Images after rotating by 90:

[image] [image]

Images after rotating by any other number (not a multiple of 90) eg 45:

[image]

As can be seen in the image, the tip of the arrow has been cropped out of the image. Could anyone please tell me why this is happening? Again, multiples of 90 are fine, it's just any other number where the unusual cropping occurs.

```
$props = ['w' => 74, 'h' => 74];
$angle = 360 - $_GET['angle'];

$final_img = imagecreatetruecolor($props['w'], $props['h']);
imagesavealpha($final_img, true);
$transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($final_img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($final_img, 0, 0, $transColor);

$rotate = imagecreatefrompng('arrow.png');
$src = imagerotate($rotate, $angle, $transColor); //rotated my image

$src_x = ImageSX($src); //find out new x width
$src_y = ImageSY($src); //find out new y height

$src_widthx = $src_x/2 - $props['w']/2;  // divide each by 2 and then subtract desired end width from wider rotated width
$src_heighty = $src_y/2 - $props['h']/2;  // and again for height

imagecopy($final_img, $src, 0, 0, $src_widthx, $src_heighty, $props['w'], $props['h']);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($final_img);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate a square of `nXm` pixels by lets say `45` degrees you will get the diagonals(which are bigger than n or m and equal sqrt(n^2+m^2)) of the image be the new rotated image width and height.

The function crops the rotated image using the original dimensions of the image, namely n and m.

A way to fix the problem would be by crating a bigger blank image with the appropriate size, sqrt(width_original_image^2+height_original_image^2), and than copy the original image to the new image using imagecopy. After that you can use imagerotate on the new image

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amitay. Could you recommend a solution for achieving what I want to in another way or by modifying my code?

Comment: What is `n` and what is `m`? In order for me to accept your answer I will need a bit more detail

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Unfortunately a bigger blank image does not solve the problem, no matter the size of the blank image that is created the arrow always appears cropped.

Answer (score 0):

I installed and used the ImageMagick PHP library and the rotations show uncropped, no matter the degree of rotation.